# Proof of Intergral formula

Tags: contour-integration, hypergeometric-function

I have to verify for $\Re a>0$
$$\operatorname{F}\left(a,b,c;x\right)=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(1+a-c)}{\Gamma(a)}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}{s^{a-1}(s-1)^{c-a-1}(1-xs)^{-b}ds}$$

where $C$ is a counterclockwise loop that passes through the origin and encloses the point $s = 1$

I started with the integral formula
$$\operatorname{F}\left(a,b,c;x\right)=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}\left(a,c-a\right)}\int_{0}^{1}{s^{a-1}(s-1)^{c-a-1}(1-xs)^{-b}ds}\\
=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_{0}^{1}{s^{a-1}(s-1)^{c-a-1}(1-xs)^{-b}ds}$$
using the Euler's Reflection formula
$$=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(1+a-c)\sin{\pi a}}{\Gamma(a)\pi}\int_{0}^{1}{s^{a-1}(s-1)^{c-a-1}(1-xs)^{-b}ds}\\
=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(1+a-c)\left(e^{i\pi a}-e^{-i\pi a}\right)}{\Gamma(a)2\pi i}\int_{0}^{1}{s^{a-1}(s-1)^{c-a-1}(1-xs)^{-b}ds}$$

Now the question is how do I change the contour to run along the interval $\left[0, 1\right]$ and back
Please Help

Comment: Collapse $C$ on the two sides of $\left[ 0,1 \right]$ and take into account that the integrand has different values on the two sides due to the multivaluedness of the power functions.

Comment: @Gary Can you please write it in terms of integrals, I don't understand i'm so sorry

Comment: Also, when you use the integralformula on $(0,1)$ the integrand should contain $1-s$ and not $s-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you collapse the contour on the two sides of $\left[ {0,1} \right]$, you obtain
\begin{align*}
& \int_C^{} {s^{a - 1} (s - 1)^{c - a - 1} (1 - xs)^{ - b} ds} \\ & = \int_0^1 {s^{a - 1} (e^{ - \pi i} (1 - s))^{c - a - 1} (1 - xs)^{ - b} ds}  + \int_1^0 {s^{a - 1} (e^{\pi i} (1 - s))^{c - a - 1} (1 - xs)^{ - b} ds} 
\\ & =-2i\sin (\pi (a - c))\int_0^1 {s^{a - 1} (1 - s)^{c - a - 1} (1 - xs)^{ - b} ds} .
\end{align*}
Now just use the reflection formula for the gamma function.

Comment: Thank you so much I get it now